# Environment.TickCount alternative in Xamarin iOS 11.2

Tags: c#, ios, time, xamarin.ios

It looks like Environment.TickCount at least in iOS 11.2 has changed it's behaviour. On my iPad with iOS 10.3 it returns count of milliseconds from device start. But on iPhone with iOS 11.2 it returns 560066914, and after couple of minutes - 560066431 which is less, and device wasn't restarted!

Is there another way to get time since device start? I need it to check whether user changed time settings since last launch of my app.

Answer (score 1):

Solved simply:

```
#if __IOS__
            long run =  (long)(NSProcessInfo.ProcessInfo.SystemUptime * 1000);
#else
            long run = System.Environment.TickCount;
#endif
```

---

Update:

NSProcessInfo.ProcessInfo.SystemUptime returns wrong values as well. It looks like apple broke TickCount in iOS 11 and now you can't rely on it. "Those bast*rds!" (r)

Answer (score 0):

You can find all the information you need in [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.tickcount?view=netframework-4.7.2):

> The TickCount property cycles between Int32.MinValue, which is a negative number, and Int32.MaxValue once every 49.8 days.
>
> Because the value of the TickCount property value is a 32-bit signed integer, if the system runs continuously, TickCount will increment from zero to Int32.MaxValue for approximately 24.9 days, then jump to Int32.MinValue, which is a negative number, then increment back to zero during the next 24.9 days. You can work around this issue by calling the Windows GetTickCount function, which resets to zero after approximately 49.7 days, or by calling the GetTickCount64 function.

If you measure `DateTime.Now` and `Environment.TickCount & Int32.MaxValue` (which is a positive number and resets every 24.9 days) you can find out whether the user has changed the time or not.

Comment: As I wrote _it was true_ but at least in 11.2 TickCount returns only some value, it is not the uptime anymore. It returns 560067873, ... , 560105705, 560106721, 560107746, and when I restart my app (less then minute later): 560067233,560068258 and so on. So It always starts from smaller values than ended  in the previous app launch.